# Why does Python code runs slower if I use muliple processes

Tags: python, performance, python-multiprocessing, pool

Hello I'm very depressed at the moment because of failing to speed up my Code:
I tried different stuff and now I used Multiprocessor Pools. To evaluate the speedup and effects of the Processornumbers I variate the number of processors I use. However, I lose speed if I increase the number of processors. I dont know why because in theory I compute 8 images parallel if i have 8 processes and 4 if I use 4 processes. Sure there is an overhead but this should not be such a big bottleneck. Does anyone spot the mistake here? Kind regards Max

```
'''
Created on 17.11.2017

@author: Max
'''
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, sys, errno
import re
import argparse
from time import time
import multiprocessing
import glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
def computeFeatures(input, chunk_num):
    thresholded_chunk = []
    #print("Processing Chunk,",chunk_num)
    cv2.threshold(input,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    cv2.threshold(input,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    cv2.threshold(input,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    cv2.threshold(input,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    thresholded_chunk.append(cv2.threshold(input,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV))   
    return (thresholded_chunk, chunk_num)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_Proc = 2
    max_Proc = 20
    while num_Proc != max_Proc:

        start = time()
        # Handle command line options
        numProcessors = num_Proc

        # Start my pool
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(numProcessors)

        # Build task list
        path = "InputSimulation\*" 
        tasks = []
        image_list= []
        img_idx = 0
        image_pathes = glob.glob(path+".jpg")
        results = []
        index_for_chunk = numProcessors
        while img_idx < len(image_pathes):
            #print("InsterImageNumber",img_idx)
            tasks.append( (cv2.imread(image_pathes[img_idx],0), img_idx, ) )
            if img_idx % numProcessors == 0:
                result = [pool.apply_async( computeFeatures, t ) for t in tasks]
                results.append(result)
                tasks = []
            img_idx +=1
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
            # Run tasks    #Flatten list before print

        end = time()
        print("DURATION FOR " +str(num_Proc) +" PROCESSES",end - start)
        num_Proc +=1
        # Process results
```

Comment: This may be an issue with your hardware, would you post the specs on the machine you are running it on including GPU specs.

Comment: If your process is IO limited rather than CPU limited, then spanning multiple ones together often slows down the whole thing.

Comment: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6500U CPU 2.5Ghz 2 Cores 4 logic Processors, Windows 10, 8GB Ram, Intel(R) HD Graphics 520

Answer (score 0):

Since your not using any callback function with apply_async and always use the same function (computeFeatures) you are better of using Pool.map(). In your current use case apply_async will not preform any computations in parallel. On top of that it will add overhead for each computation.

Example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from math import sqrt

p = Pool(8)
num_list = range(100000)

%%time
_ = p.map(sqrt, num_list)
```

> CPU times: user 19 ms, sys: 2.36 ms, total: 21.4 ms
>
> Wall time: 27.7 ms

```
%%time
_ = [sqrt(num) for num in num_list]
```

> CPU times: user 33.7 ms, sys: 5.93 ms, total: 39.6 ms
>
> Wall time: 37.5 ms

```
%%time
_ = [p.apply_async(sqrt, num) for num in num_list]
```

> CPU times: user 5.5 s, sys: 1.37 s, total: 6.87 s
>
> Wall time: 5.95 s

As shown by this example. Simple computation is best done with Pool.map() Change your code into using map and you might see some improvement. Also its important to find the correct number of workers for your system and problem at hand.

```
result = pool.map(computeFeatures, tasks)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I changed the line according to result = pool.map(computeFeatures, tasks) but its running even slower.